# How to copy paste data based on some criterias from one workbook to another(specific cells) using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, copy-paste

I have written below code for copying the data from one workbook to specific cells in another workbook (that's challenge I think, destination file has months and relevant data below it, each month I need to copy the data to the current month column, that's why used "last column" function not to overwrite historical months also to make it dynamic to go to the last column where there is no data which current month ). Even though code is working fine I want to optimize it in order debug easily and avoid future problems when for ex;  current year changed. *Do you have any ideas how can i make this code better*?

**Code**

```
Dim  x, LastRow, LastColumn, workfile, sourcefile As String
 
 sourcefile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 workfile = ThisWorkbook.Name


LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 1).Value = "001B" And Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 2).Value = "GBP" Then
    Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 8).Copy
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Activate
    Lastcolumn2 = Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(28, 21).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(28, Lastcolumn2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else

End If

If Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 1).Value = "001R" And Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 2).Value = "GBP" Then
    Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 8).Copy
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Activate
    Lastcolumn3 = Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(29, 21).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(29, Lastcolumn3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
End If

If Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 1).Value = "001B" And Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 2).Value = "EUR" Then
    Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 8).Copy
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Activate
    Lastcolumn4 = Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(35, 21).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(35, Lastcolumn4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
    End If
    
If Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 1).Value = "001R" And Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 2).Value = "EUR" Then
    Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 8).Copy
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Activate
    Lastcolumn5 = Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(36, 21).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(36, Lastcolumn5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
    End If
    Next
```

Comment: This question may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to determine what the target row is for each of your conditions, then just plug that value into the code block you want to execute. This way you cut out having the same code repeated multiple times.

Here is how you would do that:

```
Dim  x, LastRow, LastColumn, workfile, sourcefile, exchangedownload1, exchangedownload2 As String
Dim targetRow As Integer

sourcefile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
workfile = ThisWorkbook.Name

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

    ' store the values you are wanting to examine in these 2 variables
    exchangedownload1 = Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 1).Value
    exchangedownload2 = Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 2).Value

    ' determine the value for targetRow in this Case statement
    Select Case exchangedownload2
        Case Is "GBP"
            If exchangedownload1 = "001B" Then
                targetRow = 28
            ElseIf enchangedownload1 = "001R" Then
                targetRow = 29
        Case Is "EUR"
            If exchangedownload1 = "001B" Then
                targetRow = 35
            ElseIf enchangedownload1 = "001R" Then
                targetRow = 36
    End Select

    ' this is your code block that was being repeated with just a 
    ' different value for your targetRow, so just plug the value for 
    ' targetRow where it belongs and you only have to have this code block once
    Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 8).Copy
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Activate
    Lastcolumn2 = Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(targetRow, 21).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(targetRow, Lastcolumn2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next
```

Comment: ' determine the value for targetRow in this Case statement
    Select Case xrate2
        Case Is = GBP
            If xrate1 = "001B" Then
                targetrow = 28
            ElseIf xrate1 = "001R" Then
                targetrow = 29
       Select Case xrate2
       Case Is = EUR
            If xrate1 = "001B" Then
                targetrow = 35
            ElseIf xrate1 = "001R" Then
                targetrow = 36
        End Select    "This part didn't work out as it says Compile error: End select without Select Case.

Comment: @NigarHuseynzade I don't understand your comment, what are you trying to communicate? do you have a question about my answer or are you having problems implementing it?

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear, I am having problems while implementing above code which you wrote it was showing error and I changed it a bit but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: workfile]

So this the screenshot of the "workfile" where I need to copy the data each month under relevant month column. Impact Rate of Change area just formulas and calculation. So copied are is before that: empty columns currently starting from August, bcoz I ran it already for the July, as I said it works but code seems too complex and hard to debug for another person

Answer (score 0):

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    ' store the values you are wanting to examine in these 2 variables
    xrate1 = Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 1).Value
    xrate2 = Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 2).Value

    ' determine the value for targetRow in this Case statement
    Select Case xrate2
        Case "GBP"
    Select Case xrate1
        Case "001B": targetrow = 28
    Case Else: targetrow = 29
    End Select
    Select Case xrate2
        Case "EUR"
    Select Case xrate1
        Case "001B": targetrow = 35
     Case Else: targetrow = 36
    End Select

    ' copying data
    Workbooks(sourcefile).Worksheets("exchangedownload").Cells(x, 8).Copy
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Activate
    Lastcolumn2 = Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(targetrow, 21).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Workbooks(workfile).Worksheets("A").Cells(targetrow, Lastcolumn2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
```

Above is the adjusted one as I couldn't use If statement with Case, Case is replacement of If, Elseif. But still receiving compile error saying it is "Next without For" and End Select without Case statement((